# Последовательный алгоритм генерации из списка Python

Tags: python, алгоритм, список, генераторы

Мне нужен генератор, который из списка `lettrs`

```
rawlettrs = "01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
lettrs = list(rawlettrs)
```

генерировал бы бесконечное количество своеобразных "кодов".
Вот как должен выглядеть выход (запятые замените на переносы строк, в квадратных скобках мои пометки, которых не должно быть в генерации):

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, [Несколько миллисекунд спустя], Y, Z, a, b, [Еще мгновение...], z, 00, 01, 01, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0A, [Еще пару миллисекунд спустя], 0z, 10, 11, 12, 13, [Пропустим некоторое время], zy, zz, 000, [И так до бесконечности]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def weird_gen():
    rawlettrs = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    for lettr in rawlettrs:
        yield lettr
    for prefix in weird_gen():
        for lettr in rawlettrs:
            yield prefix + lettr
```

Comment: Можно один типичный вопрос чайника? В какой переменной генерируется сам код-выход?

Comment: @ДенисОрлов Ни в какой конкретно. :) Код-выход - это то, что возвращает `yield` (сначала первый, потом второй). Т.е. либо `lettr`, либо `prefix + lettr`. А `prefix`, в свою очередь, это результат работы этого же генератора. Короче, это рекурсивный генератор. Как у него символы заканчиваются он подключает себя же, чтобы генерировать символ левее. А как у того второго закончатся, то он (второй) подключает третий экземпляр себя. И т.д.

Comment: Ну это я понял. Просто в моем случае нужно записать этот выход в переменную для дальнейшей работы с кодом. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Использовать стандартно, как и любой другой генератор (например `range()`). `for x in weird_gen():      print(x)`. Или `gen = weird_gen();  x = next(gen); print(x); x = next(gen); print(x); ...`.

Comment: Все заработало. Благодарю :)

Comment: А стек из-за рекурсии сломаться может?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Это ж сколько ему надо нагенерировать на такой длинной строке чтобы до 1000 вложенности дойти?... Если строка для генератора будет состоять из одного символа, то да, до 1000 дойдёт и сломается. А если хотя бы из двух символов, то это уже 2^1000 (примерно 10^300) вариантов. К примеру, терабайт - это всего лишь 2^40. А на строке из вопроса, я не уверен, что и до десятой вложенности можно дойти за вменяемое время.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru 1000 символов в длину - это более чем сверхдостаточно. Я же выше расписал, что для исходной строки в всего-лишь 2 символа чтобы сгенерировать терабайт комбинаций строка дойдёт только до длины 40. До 1000 она не вырастет и за всю жизнь. А при при исходной строке в 62 символа как в задании, я тут прикинул, на моём компе нужно будет около 100 лет непрерывного генерирования чтобы достичь длины 10. Длина в 4 символа достигается за 0.05 секунд, 5 символов - за 3 секунды, 6 символов - за 3 минуты, 7 - должно быть за 3 часа, 8  - за 8 дней, 9 - за почти полтора года.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import count, combinations_with_replacement

def gen():
    rawletters = "01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    for length in count(1):
        for res in combinations_with_replacement(rawletters, length):
            yield ''.join(res)
```

Comment: [E741](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E741.html)

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, поправил)

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, тогда уж и к соседнему ответу это относится, кстати.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с `product`(по сути, переделка ответа @Кирилл Малышев)

```py
from itertools import product, count

def gen():
    alphabet = "01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    for length in count(1):
        for res in product(alphabet, repeat=length):
            yield ''.join(res)
```